# Sizzle.js ( JQuery Selector Engine ) error/bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, sizzle

Well, I've been trying to make this, maybe I am constructing it wrong or it's a known bug in jquery selector :

```
$(':not(.class) > *').each( function(){

});
```

The code meant to get all elements expect those that are children of element with class `.class` :

```
<div class="class">
    <a> Hi 1 </a> <!-- This shouldn't be selected -->
</div>
<div class="something">
    <a> Hi 2 </a> <!-- This should be selected -->
</div>
```

Comment: Is requirement for selector to return all elements in document or only `div` elements that are not `.class` ?

Comment: It seems to be working for me with the latest jQuery.

Comment: @guest271314 I think OP wants to select `a` elements.

Comment: @guest271314 No I don't want, I want everything, I just used a elements as simple.

Comment: @AhmedAlaa _"No I don't want, I want everything, I just used a elements as simple."_ Not certain interpret correctly ? You only want `a` element - or all elements in document ?

Comment: I want all elements expect those that are in (.class)

Comment: @Gothdo Well, I tried again and didn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/71/)**

I think that what you looking for :

```
$(':not(.class *)').each( function(){

});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `class` is logged at `console.` . `:not(.class)` will return `html` , `body` elements as well

Comment: Hmm, That's fine, but this is actually not like css selector, I thought that I should select exactly as I select within css file.

Comment: @guest271314 is logged but it;s children isn't.

Comment: @Zakaria May I have your permission for a private talk(chat) ?!